# PHPMailer question

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am getting the error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Invalid address: ' etc. etc. etc. and it is a real eye sore on the page.

So I want to capture the error or suppress it or something - and then have it be returned to the form so the user can be told there is an error and to re-input their email address. All this will be neat and tidy and not the mess of an error it is now.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you passing in proprer RFC 822-type addresses? PHP Mailer wouldn't complain about an invalid one unless you were actually providing one that's truly invalid. Could be something as simple as a variable not set properly or out-of-scope and not global'd.

Answer (score 4):

```
try {
    // your code which sends the email
} catch (phpmailerException $exception) {
    // process the exception here
    // or leave this block blank to just suppress it(which is a bad idea)
}
```

also, see [exception man page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: OK, I was looking at the link - and is usual with PHP their help confuses me more than it ever helps.

I would have no idea where to even implement this since phpmailer is the code actually sending the mail. I just tell it what to send and from waht mail server.

Thanks